# Syntax error - jQuery Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

could you tell me why this code causes syntax error when loaded from file but works from console? At the beginning of work with it I was thinking that maybe `'` colons cause the errors, but escaping them didn't help. What's the cause?

```
var html = "<ins class=\'adsbygoogle\' style=\'display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px\' data-ad-client=\'ca-pub-4197522922628043\' data-ad-slot=\'8168313894\'></ins><script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>";
```

Comment: I was expecting I could dynamically add an add with `jQuery("selector").append(html);` but stucked on the issue above.

Comment: Google do not allow display Ads by jQ o JS.

Comment: the /s in </script> causes the problem